# How come I can't craft enhanced ursine gauntlets, though enh. ursine chestplate was possible

Tags: the-witcher-3

In Witcher 3 I'm fairly sure I've gotten all the Witcher diagrams of the 3 schools, griffin, cat & bear. I decided to go for the ursine armour set. I've made mastercrafted ursine boots and chestplate, though I'm not give the option to create enhanced gauntlets or trousers.

Is this because I have previously created enhanced ursine gauntlets/trousers and sold them? (If so, I don't remember.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have the diagram (visible from the menu) for enhanced ursine gauntlets, you can't craft them. While you're in the menu, make sure you also have the standard ursine gauntlets needed to create the enhanced version.
Although I'm assuming you know that step since you have 2 of the other parts mastercrafted.
If all else fails, just Google the location of that diagram and see if you are able to get it (I had to do this for cat school I believe).
If the diagram is gone from the physical location and you have standard ursine gauntlets (and other required materials) AND you're unable to craft them still, my guess would be some weird glitch that caused the diagram to not get included with the others in the crafting menu...

Good luck!